# check if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{7k-2}{8k-3 \sqrt{k}}\right)}^k$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

How to check if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{7k-2}{8k-3 \sqrt{k}}\right)}^k$ [converges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20as%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity%20(((7k-2)%2F(8k-3*sqrt(k))))%5Ek)?.

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{7k-2}{8k-3 \sqrt{k}}\right)}^k &=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}{ \left( \frac{7k-2}{8k-3 \sqrt{k}}\right)}^k \\
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}{ \left( \frac{7\frac{k}{k}-2\frac{1}{k}}{8\frac{k}{k}-3 \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k}}\right)}^k \\
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}{ \left( \frac{7-2\frac{1}{k}}{8-3 \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k}}\right)}^k \\
\end{align}$

Am I on the right track ? If so, how should I go on ? I need some help to do it without the root test.

Comment: [Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), what have you tried?

Comment: My original idea was to make it so $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{7}{8} \right)^k }$ will be left and I can argument as the geometric series. But I am not sure if I am allowed to do that. 
And I failed doing the ratio test... The root test is not in my script and thus I do not use that technique here

Comment: It's really easy to apply the ratio test, you almost completed half of the work. Not so easy as root test though ...

Comment: @rtybase ok, thanks. I was able to make it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that eventually

$$0<\frac{7k-2}{8k-3 \sqrt{k}}\le c<1$$

Comment: _* for sufficiently large $k$_

Comment: @orlp yes of course, I've added eventually

Comment: So can I just take the limit inside the sum ? And use your point?

Comment: @jublikon thus it converges by root test (since in the limit it behaves like a geometric series $r^n$ with $0<r<1$)

Comment: That's not what you want to say. After all $$0< \frac{k}{k+1} < 1$$ for all $k,$ but $\sum \left (\dfrac{k}{k+1} \right )^k = \infty.$

Comment: you are absolutely right, I’ve  better  precised what I meant

Answer (score 5):

It should be
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\left(\dfrac{7k-2}{8k-3\sqrt{k}}\right)^{k}\right)^{1/k}=\dfrac{7}{8}<1,
\end{align*}
by root test, it is convergent.